# High CPU load for dynamic classification

Tags: dynamic, machine-learning, system-performance

I encountered some issues with extremely high CPU load when I tried to classify live images (using `Dynamic` and `CurrentImage[]`). Because I couldn't figure out what went wrong I tried to find a simpler example and found that the following produces the same high CPU load:

```
trainingset = {1 -> "A", 2 -> "A", 3.5 -> "B", 4 -> "B"}; 
c = Classify[trainingset]; 
Dynamic[c@RandomReal[4], UpdateInterval -> 1]
```

- For `UpdateInterval->1` the WolframKernel process produces a CPU load
  between 80% and 120%.
- For `UpdateInterval->0` the WolframKernel process produces a CPU load
  around 300%.

I already asked this question in the [chat a few days ago](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30615809#30615809) and one user could confirm this while another could not replicate the behavior.

I run Mathematica 10.4.0.0 on a 2014 Retina Macbook Pro (2.2 GHz i7-4770HQ) under OS X 10.11.3.

The picture below shows the CPU load as reported by the OS X activity monitor (load >100% can be interpreted as multiple cores being stressed; thus on a 4-core machine with hyper-threading **800%** load equals 100% for the processor as a whole)

[image: activity monitor]

Comment: What exactly does a CPU load greater than 100% mean?

Comment: It is a 4-core machine, the maximum load is 400% (100% per physical core) as reported by activity monitor in OS X

Comment: I just figured out that the virtual cores (due to hyper threading) are accounted for in the total CPU load too. Thus on a 4(physical)-core machine the maximum load is 800%. I actually didn't look at the CPU load at first but wondered why my machine ran hot. Is this behavior expected from classification? I assumed once trained classification would be computationally cheap.

Comment: With `UpdateInterval -> 2` does the CPU stay high or does it work and rest? What version are you using?